# Angular 2 - Global component approach

Tags: angular

Which is the best approach if I want a component to be globally accessible, for example a login modal.

1. Declare a new one in each component view
2. Instance a new one dynamically when I need it
3. Declare one on AppComponent, make a function to manage it and inject AppComponent on the component that need to use it.
4. Other?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the logic for your modal only once, and register it everywhere where you need it to be presented.

It will make your code clear, and once a developer comes to some part of your application he will see `ModalComponent` registered, so he will understand why it is using in partial of the current component.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If I do that and register the modal component for example in an "item list component" I will have the html associated to the modal several times instead of one, that's ok?

Comment: Yes, your component  - `ItemListComponent` use it, so, you registered it for it, and then use it in HTML. Once you will need somewhere else modal, you will do the same thing. Not sure what do you mean HTML associated. ModalComponent it is something already with partial, with HTML, so everything you need to use it - to include selector, like `<my-modal></my-modal>` .

Comment: What I tried to say is that for example if the modal component has a template with big html, In the resultant html I will have that html many times as items.

Comment: You don't have to duplicate code of the modal component. While you creating a component - you attach to it HTML partial once. Then you use  the selector, that's it. If you mean a rendered HTML will have big HTML, and logically you can pull out on the one level your modal, this probably solution for you. But to give more clear answer, it is better to see your code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to the rendered html, I want that the modal html be present only once on the rendered html.

Comment: I see, so you need to pull it on the level higher of your component hierarchy. For instance, You will have AppComponent -> ItemListComponent. So, you need to include ModalComponent to AppComponent, and trigger event from ItemListComponent, which will says ModalComponent to show up!

Comment: Exactly! With the difference that I have much more components in between, something like AppComponent -> SomePageComponent -> ListComponent -> ItemListComponent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124421/discussion-between-mikki-and-diego-gonzalez).